# Android: Balancing market presence, API function availability, and approach to cleint/server authentication

Tags: android, authorization, google-play-services

I want to use Google Play Services so that I can access Google Saved Games API which allows me to seamlessly obtain authorisation tokens using `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(...)` for secure server authentication on my server back end. However this function is only available through Google Play Services [r29](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8487000_r29.zip) which requires at least Android 6.0. On the other hand my actual game only requires at least Android 2.3.1.

I'm a little concerned that according to [this website](https://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/) Android 6.0 is only available on around 7.5% of Android devices, which kind of reduces my impact as of right now in the market.

**My question is** - what are the alternative approaches (API's) to server authentication, especially given that Android [recommend](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) using `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(...)` for security reasons?

---

**What I've found so far**

[This website](http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions) gives a more encouraging estimate. I suppose as time goes on the earlier Android versions will diminish and 6.0 will become more popular...

Adding more to the confusion, I just found out that the `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(...)` approach is now deprecated, even though it was relatively recently recommended as best practice by Google.

Maybe [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) could be of help. There's also this Google page on the Google [Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth), which states:

> Software can obtain OAuth 2.0 Access tokens in a variety of ways, depending on the platform where the code is running. For details, see [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html) and [Google Play Services Authorization](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html).

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/whats-new-in-google-play-services-83.html) could possibly solve the deprecation problem, but still requires Android 6.0+...

---

**Tentative solution**

Following the advice in noogui's answer below, I currently seem to be making progress. Using [google-play-services_lib (r28)](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8298000_r28.zip) allows me to use Android 2.3.1. This approach also seems to solve the deprecation warnings.

Ok, noogui's answer above put me in the right direction. However, this made me think I had to sign in twice - once for Google Play Saved Games - and once again for GoogleSignInApi's due to the following:

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(...);
```

A bit more digging lead me to maclir's self-answered question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730365/oauth-token-with-google-play-game-services), from which I could clearly see how to obtain an authentication token using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` by **only** logging into Google Play Services, without having to invoke a second log via `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(...)`. This way seems to work fine...

... But [this official Android blog post](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide) declares that method to be deprecated due to security issues, but does offer a solution using `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestIdToken(...)`, which will presumably **not** require me to use `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(...)`, as was believed by me from noogui's answer.

I am going to test this next. Hopefully I will be able to get the token from `GoogleSignInOptions.Builder.requestIdToken(...)` by just signing into Google Saved Games API, and **not** have to login in to GoogleSignInAPI via `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(...)` as well...

Answer (score 0):

> If you use Google Sign-In with an app or site that communicates with a
>   backend server, you might need to identify the currently signed-in
>   user on the server. To do so securely, after a user successfully signs
>   in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the
>   server, verify the integrity of the ID token and retrieve the user's
>   ID from the sub claim of the ID token. You can use user IDs
>   transmitted in this way to safely identity the currently signed-in
>   user on the backend.

**Send the ID token to your server**

After a user successfully signs in, get the user's ID token:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
    mIdTokenTextView.setText("ID Token: " + idToken);
    // TODO(user): send token to server and validate server-side
} else {
    mIdTokenTextView.setText("ID Token: null");
}
```

Full code implementation is found in the [Authenticate with a Backend Server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) guide.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help me with obtaining an authorization token which I can then send to my server to be verified.

Comment: Thanks, does this approach happen silently? I'm using Google Saved Games API to deal with leaderboard and achievements, so it would be nice not to have to sign in twice, e.g. once for saved games API and once for the GoogleSignInApi API. I'll look into it.

Comment: That and other Sign-In concerns are addressed in this official guide [Implementing Sign-in in Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin).

Comment: I can't find where my problem is addressed in that link you give. How can i get an auth token from Google Save Games API? I want to avoid signing in twice via diff APIs. There is a deprecated server auth token function under r29 google play services, but this requires at least Android 6 and my target is Android 2.3.1.  Plus that particular function is deprecated already !! I could use GoogleAuthUtil as in this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730365/oauth-token-with-google-play-game-services ...  but Google say this method is unsafe. I can't seem to win :-( ... i will keep trying.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069681/should-i-use-googleauthutil-gettoken-or-not