# Should I use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...) or not?

Tags: android, web-services, authorization, google-play-services

**Background:**

I need to authenticate on my server back-end so I know the client is genuine. In my Android game I connect to `Games.API` via `GoogleApiClient`.

I only want to have to sign in once, which I want to do via `Games.API`, as this gives me many advantages (Google Play Games leaderboards, achievements, etc.)

I have been able to get an authorisation token using `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` which I can do after I sign into `Games.API`, which seems to give me a token. Good so far.

But [Google says this is not safe](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide) and says I should [migrate to ID token flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide#migrate_from_the_googleauthutil_server_auth_code_flow) instead. But, as I understand it this approach would require me to use

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

which means instigating an **additional sign in** to that for **Games.API**. Furthermore, it is not possible to `addApi` both `Games.API` **and** `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API` to the same `GoogleApiClient` !

Ok, so upgrade to the latest google-play-services (at least r29), using which I can use `Games.API` with `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(...)` to obtain an auth token for my server. But this has two problems: (1) it requires Android 6.0 or above which blocks out 80% of the market, and (2) **it's deprecated !**

---

**Question:**

Should I use `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)` or not, and if not what are my options given that I only want to sign in using `Games.API` ?

By sign in I mean present the user with log in visuals. I don't mind signing into something else so long as the user does not have to interact with the sign in...

---

**Note:**

I originally asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993528/android-balancing-market-presence-api-function-availability-and-approach-to-c) when I first started out. The current question hopefully clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I should **not** use `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...)`. It's deprecated; end of.

To achieve what I want I found the following works perfectly... whether it's the best way I have no idea.

First, sign in using `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN`:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
                                          GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestIdToken("YOUR-SERVER-CLIENT-ID")
    .build();

mGoogleApiClientForSignIn = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity, this, this)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();

mGoogleApiClientForSignIn.connect();
```

On success this will eventually call `onConnected(...)` from where you can negotiate a second sign in to Games.API. This has to be performed separately on a new `GoogleApiClient` because you can't mix `Games.API` and `Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN`:

```
mGoogleApiClientForGames = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity, this, this)
    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
    .build();

mGoogleApiClientForGames.connect();
```

As per the new [Play Games Permissions](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) update for 2016, the `GoogleSignIn` only appears once per game (even between devices !), after which the user is not presented with any visual log in screens for `GoogleSignIn`. The only visual login will be the Saved Games snapshot selection screen.

This works with Android 2.3 (use google-play-services [r28](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8298000_r28.zip)) and without deprecation warnings. Huzzah !