# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() is deprecated how can i get accessToken

Tags: android, google-plus

I was implementing google sign but i came to this method and this is deprecated show its always return null value

```
String  token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(loginActivity, accountName, scopes);
```

even i used other methods

```
 String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(loginActivity, accountName, scopes, null);
```

but it still returns null and shows as it is deprecated. Please help how can i get access token

Comment: for now you can use 
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+@aar') , it supports this method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(...) or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069681/should-i-use-googleauthutil-gettoken-or-not)

Answer (score 6):

In the below `getToken` method, I think you are passing `accountName` which is a string value.

```
String  token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(loginActivity, accountName, scopes);
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(loginActivity, accountName, scopes, null);
```

thus it will still return deprecated method `getToken`.

converting string into account before passing as mentioned below will help`:

```
Account accountDetails = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

String  token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(loginActivity, accountDetails, scopes);
```

Hope this helps.